# Is there a database schema that is apt for dynamic report generation?

Tags: database, database-design

For example,

you may have a report that joins on many tables, but in some software, they'll let you generate reports and customize the fields.

Do they accomplish this by generating views with all the joins and columns and thereby allowing the user to cherry pick the columns and conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a database schema that is apt for dynamic report generation?

A star schema.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema